# NoClassDefFoundError in spring

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

I wrote a Spring application which runs on Weblogic 10.3. In this application I have some JMS Queue consumers.

Sometimes I got an error when the application is closing or opening (I saw this error in both situation) saying:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jms/connection/SmartConnectionFactory
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:72)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:385)at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:779)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:761)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:892)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.connection.SmartConnectionFactory
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:283)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:256)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:54)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:176)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:35)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
        ... 6 more
```

Why do I get this error and what should I do to solve it? 
The version of the spring.jar is 2.5.5

Answer (score 2):

That Exception means that the class is not getting loaded into the JVM.  Make sure that the spring.jar is in the Weblogic server's classpath or library folder.

Comment: It is in my war file :) Is there any need for that?

Comment: In that case I'm guessing that you have some sort of startup/shutdown class that calls that before the war file gets loaded. I would manually try putting the jar file in server's classpath or library folder and not just in the war file.  Sometimes redundancy is the best solution.

Comment: There is no startup or shutdown class that I introduce to Weblogic, but I will give this a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

It's all very well that you have this class in your war, but in Weblogic, the war has its own classloader. Since your stack trace shows a JMS listener, I'd ask: where is the listener? If it's in the war, then you have a mystery. But it sure looks as though it's somewhere else, and it's that somewhere else that would be missing this Spring class.

Comment: Actually, the listener is in the WAR file and declared as Spring "Message Driven Pojo"