# NoClassDefFoundError on org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer during Tomcat restart

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6

Our application has a listener that consumes messages from ActiveMQ broker. However, in the production environment, we have added script to restart the Tomcat server daily. Following is the script that restart the tomcat SERVICE in the production server;

```
date /t >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log
time /t >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log
echo "Restart Tomcat Production Server" >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log
net stop "Application1" >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log timeout /T 60 /NOBREAK
net start "Application1" >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log
time /t >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log
echo "Restart_Production_Tomcats completed" >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log 
echo "" >> Restart_Production_Tomcats.log
```

Normally, during the restart, log file get following exception one time at each restart;

```
Exception in thread "org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3834" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jms/connection/SmartConnectionFactory 
at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:71) 
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:386) 
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:869) 
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:851) 
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:982) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

However, one particular day I got more than **3000** such exceptions, on that days even Tomcat couldn't restart properly. *For me, it seems like JVM classloader can not find 
`org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer` class during the restart*.

Can someone please explain what is happening when restarting tomcat and why I got this exception? However, in our development environment I can not replicate this issue or even we can not see this issue in other production environment. Is it due to restart the Tomcat server while processing messages from the ActiveMQ by listener? or some issue with restart script?

I found similar question, [NoClassDefFoundError in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014465/noclassdeffounderror-in-spring) However, I couldn't find clear answer for my question with this question.

Comment: The class it cannot find is `org/springframework/jms/connection/SmartConnectionFactory`

Comment: where do you place `SmartConnectionFactory`?

Comment: org.springframework.jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar file contains SmartConnectionFactory.class file. So, I checked in the production. This jar file appears in the application's lib file. Do we need to deploy same file in the tomcat lib folder..?? However, local development environment contains the same library setting as production, but we can not recreate this issue locally.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError throws when Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class;

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html

Therefore, it seems like JVM or classloader unable to load required class file;